# Epimorphism that is not monomorphism from $M\rightarrow M$

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory, modules

I have just finished an exercise where I prove that if $M$ is a module with acc then any epimorphism $f:M\rightarrow M$ but be an isomorphism.

I then had a think about examples of non-noetherian modules $M$ with $f:M\rightarrow M$ an epimorphism but not a monomorphism but I couldn't come up with any?

Thanks for any help

Comment: I think this question gets asked on math.SE once in a month. And it even doesn't make sense to close these questions because answers appear immediately ...

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg cool, I couldn't find it after having a look, obviously I need to master the search function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the ring $R=K[x_1,x_2,...]$ of polynomials in infinitely many variables with coefficients in the field $K$ as a $K$-module. The map $f:R\rightarrow R$ defined by
$$
f(x_1)=f(x_2)=x_1,\quad
f(x_3)=x_2,\quad
f(x_4)=x_3, \quad...
$$
has the desired property.

Comment: Instead of $K[x_1,x_2,\dotsc]$ you can simply take $R = K^{\mathbb{N}}$ (space of sequences).